# Does system() do a call like sem_post inside?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I think my code wouldn't print the text

> oh why come here!\n

but it does.

Is there something 'wrong' with `system()`? Because, when I removed it, the code ran as I wanted, halting up.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_t id0, id1;
sem_t sp; 

void *fun0(void *) {
    // When erasing the following line "system("");",
    // it block up, and doesn't print "oh why come here!\n".
    // But with it, it print the text!
    system("");
    return NULL;
}

void *fun1(void *) {
    sem_wait(&sp);
    fprintf(stderr, "oh why come here!\n");
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    sem_init(&sp, 0, 0); 
    pthread_create(&id0, 0, fun0, NULL);
    pthread_create(&id1, 0, fun1, NULL);
    void *stat0, *stat1;
    pthread_join(id0, &stat0);
    pthread_join(id1, &stat1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler: gcc 4.1.2
Linux kernel: 2.6.18

---

I compiled it with gcc 4.6.3, kernel 3.2.0, it ran as I want also.
So I think it is because of gcc 4.1.2 or kernel 2.6.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of your code is with sem_wait(), from sem_wait man page, it says:

"sem_wait()  decrements  (locks)  the  semaphore  pointed to by sem.  If the semaphore's value is greater than zero, then the decrement proceeds, and the function returns, immediately.  If the semaphore currently has the value  zero,  then  the  call blocks  until  either it becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e., the semaphore value rises above zero), or a signal handler interrupts the call."

On your code you've initialized with sp with 0, when sem_wait() decrements, it blocks and never returns since there's no other thread increments sp variable.

Comment: How can this be the right answer? If sem_wait is blocked, then the following printf could not happen. What happens is that the thread doing a system() triggers a signal (likely SIGCHILD?) which interrupts sem_wait. Check the return value of sem_wait, you'll be fixed (if I'm right, it's -EINTR).

Comment: You move around those printf() statement, you'll see why.

Answer (score 3):

The `system()` call has nothing to do with it.  My psychic powers tell me that `sem_wait` is failing with an error code instead of waiting—check the return value.  For example, I can reproduce your results on Mac OS X, because on Mac OS X, `sem_init()` always fails with `ENOSYS` ("Function not implemented"), which causes the call to `sem_wait` to then fail with `EBADF` ("Bad file descriptor").

If you add some error checking, you'll see where things go awry:

```
if(sem_init(&sp, 0, 0) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "sem_init failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
...
if(sem_wait(&sp) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "sem_wait failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

You should also crank up the warning level on your compiler—I definitely recommend using `-Wall`, and `-Wextra -pedantic` if you want to catch a lot more possible problems.  Currently, your code invokes *undefined behavior* by failing to return values from your `fun0` and `fun1` functions, which `-Wall` would warn you about.  This kind of error may not cause any obvious problems on x86, but on other architectures such as IA64, [uninitialized garbage can be deadly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx).

Comment: I add the return for fun0/1. But it is hard to believe that system("") can make sem_wait() fail.